# How to add an EasingFunction to an UWP app by code

Tags: c#, uwp, easing-functions

A solution given to me on another question was to write and add a custom easing function to my UWP code. The example provided was this piece of code:

```
public class StepEasingFunction : EasingFunctionBase
{
    public double NormalizedStep { get; set; }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new StepEasingFunction {NormalizedStep = NormalizedStep};
    }

    protected override double EaseInCore(double normalizedTime)
    {
        var stepIndex = Math.Round(normalizedTime / NormalizedStep);
        return NormalizedStep * stepIndex;
    }
}
```

I searched the web and try different ways to implement this code in my app but I'm not able to. I don't know if this code goes into my namespace or I need to create an external class.

If I put the code in my namespace I'm getting errors EaseInCore and CreateInstanceCore:

```
no suitable method found to override
```

and on Freezable:

```
Freezable does not exist in the namesape
```

I have read Microsoft and other sites info on easing functions but none shows a complete example on how to implement this in UWP C# code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EasingFunctionBase` that you posted is a WPF (System.Windows) class. Unfortunately that class is not extensible on UWP (see this forum post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/81e9d88b-70c7-4ba2-92bf-7c3890b91f81/uwpeasingfunctionbase-uwp-how-to).

In your case you will likely need to use a custom animation in code, or use keyframes to simulate a different curve. You can also look at the [Visual Layer API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/composition-animation) which does allow you to create custom easing functions.

Comment: Thanks for your info Robertos. Very good to know. In my previous post where I got the code, II made the mistake of setting a tag to WPF instead of UWP. That explains everything. In the next few days, I will take the time to read on Visual Layer APi.